# Dominio app no responde

Tags: linux, nginx, dominio

He adquirido un dominio .app en godaddy, esta redirigido a mi IP pero pasa lo siguiente:

Si accedo por curl, wget o lynx desde la consola, llego perfectamente y me muestra lo que tiene que mostrar.  El ping me devuelve la IP que corresponde. Pero si quiero acceder desde cualquier browser se va por Timeout y del lado del server no obtengo ningún mensaje que defina si hay algún error.

EN GoDaddy tengo configurado el DNS como

**@    A     XXX.XXX.XXX -> DIRECCION IP DE UN SERVER AWS**

**WWW   CNAME   DOMINIO.APP**

Del lado del server tengo nginx.

Alguna idea ? . Será alguna restricción de los bowser con el dominio .app ?  por qué desde wget o lynx si puedo acceder ?.

Gracias

Comment: ¿Qué quieres decir con *lo apunté a mi IP*? ¿Revisaste el log de errores del servidor?

Comment: En Godday configuré el Dominio para que apunte a la IP del server  " @ A XXX.XXX.XXX"

Comment: Para comprender mejor... el hosting está en GoDaddy ¿cierto?  ¿Y el dominio, dónde lo tienes contratado?

Comment: No . El Hosting esta en un AWS y en Godaddy esta el Dominio.

Comment: Eso es lo primero que deberías haber explicado en tu pregunta. Luego tienes que indicar cómo has hecho la redirección, qué registro has llenado y cómo lo has llenado, para ver si está bien. Y si todo está bien, ten en cuenta que eso puede tardar un tiempo (algunas horas generalmente)  para propagarse. Sugiero que revises [este enlace](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=259099) con algunas indicaciones al respecto.

Comment: Te agradezco. Ahora voy a editar mi pregunta.  La verdad que generé para saber si alguien tuvo drama con el Dominio .app ya que no hay muchas ciencia. Y lo que mas me llama la atención es que puedo acceder desde la consola, pero no desde un Browser. ( Ambos en la Misma PC  )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema se presenta debido a que Google hace un preload del dominio .app y lo fuerza a trabajar en HTTPS, y era por eso que me daba error de Timeout ya que el Servidor AWS no lo tenía configurado para aceptar HTTPS.

Fuente http://get.app

**Your security is our priority. The .app top-level domain is included on the HSTS preload list, making HTTPS required on all connections to .app websites — no individual HSTS registration or configuration required. The result is built-in web security for you and your users.**

Perdón por la molestia y espero le sirva a alguien mas.